# Override a content page in drupal 7

Tags: nodes

There is any way to override the content page of a particular content type in drupal 7.

By default the content page has the sidebar on the right hand side and the content is placed on the left side

```
 Page design:

 Content- width 650px | Left sidebar 500px
```

Here if the content type is company_profile then the width of the content type should be 1050px and the side bar should be below the content page with width 500px as show in the below image

[image]

Can anyone help me how to override the content page when the content type is company_profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use hook_preprocess_node() and if the content type is company_profile, change the styling. Or you can have a node--company_profile.tpl.php file and render that particular content type the way you want.

Then you can use CSS to do get things done. If you use a grid based layout such as 960.gs, this would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Overriding Page Templates per Content Type in Drupal 7](http://www.digett.com/blog/01/11/2012/overriding-page-templates-content-type-drupal-7) for a full overview, but basically you need to implement this in your theme's template.php file:

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to create content type specific page template files like `page--article.tpl.php` and `page--page.tpl.php`...or for your particular case, `page--company_profile.tpl.php`.

Remember to clear Drupal's cache after you do either of the above, otherwise the theme registry won't be updated with your changes.

Answer (score 0):

This you shall do entirely from your theme file (yourtheme.info) by redefining the region names; The rest is css float job and #region-name width setting.

For a particular content-type use this pattern:
node--CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php
e.g.
node--company_profile.tpl.php

where you copy the node.tpl.php content and edit according to you own wish.

Comment: I need not to change the entire content page.I have to change the content page only for a particular content type say company_profile