# Content Type template override - Dash or Underscore?

Tags: theming, nodes

I am looking for some clarification on whether to use and underscore ("_") or a dash ("-") when creating a page template override for a content type. [Some tutorials and articles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/override-a-content-page-in-drupal-7) say the format should use underscores such as ...

`page--content_type_name.tpl.php`

while [others](http://www.digett.com/blog/01/11/2012/overriding-page-templates-content-type-drupal-7) specify the format as dashes like ...

`page--content-type-name.tpl.php`

If my content type has a multi-word name how should the template override filename be formatted?

Comment: Both seem to work fine for me, have you tried them?

Comment: I have tried both and only the underscore works for me.

Comment: Hmm must be the theme I'm using or something but yeah, now you mention it the method with underscores has always worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [`theme_get_suggestions()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7), there is a comment:

```
// When we discover templates in @see drupal_find_theme_templates,
// hyphens (-) are converted to underscores (_) before the theme hook
// is registered. We do this because the hyphens used for delimiters
// in hook suggestions cannot be used in the function names of the
// associated preprocess functions. Any page templates designed to be used
// on paths that contain a hyphen are also registered with these hyphens
// converted to underscores so here we must convert any hyphens in path
// arguments to underscores here before fetching theme hook suggestions
// to ensure the templates are appropriately recognized.
```

If you look at a preprocess, like [`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7), you will see things like:

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $node->type;
```

This is using the machine name of the content type directly, which is underscored.

`--` is a delimiter between things, underscores are used within a thing.